# Spring-Boot 2.1.2 and class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

My Sprint boot application is not coming up because it's complaining about missing class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value, but I have jackson library as dependency, so I think it might be possible some conflict.

SPRING LOG:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.2.RELEASE)

00:22:54.084 [main      ] ERROR ngframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter - Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value
00:22:55.063 [main      ] ERROR         org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
```

`pom.xml` (dependencies):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Has anybody already faced similar issue?
Thanks

Comment: Please use either the Spring Boot parent POM or BOM. Spring boot is tested against specific versions of dependencies which the BOM or POM avoid.

Answer (score 3):

jackson-core,jackson-annotations and jackson-databind jars are automatically added by spring boot.
 so you don't need to add them explicitly unless you want to override the version of the jar that are provided by spring boot .

[image]

Comment: "unless you want to override the version of the jar that are provided by spring boot" -To override you have to first `exclude` existing ones from spring-boot dependency.

Comment: @Vusal or you can set the jackson.version property if using Parent POM or place the jackson BOM before spring boots.

Comment: you can just add or manage dependency from the spring tool suite dependency management tab. if you are mentioning version then it will automatically override the  spring managed version

Answer (score 0):

Use the below version for both the artefacts:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0.pr1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, update the maven-compiler-plugin version to the latest if maven build fails.
Jackson has made some changes in the method signature of class ObjectMapper, handle the same if implemented.